# Why isn't 1900 a leap year?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, calendar-computations

I searched leap years online and found that 1900 is not, contrary to what *I* thought, a leap year. But, why is it not if 1900 is divisible by 4:
$\frac{1900}{4} = 475$

 My brother was working on his math (and he obviously got it wrong and asked me for help, so.. here I am), and the question was:
Which year, after $1899$ is a leap year?
Well, after finding that $1900$ is indeed divisible by 4, his intuition led him to believe that $1900$ was thus the next leap year. However, the answer is $1904$.

Would someone mind explaining this?

Comment: For the Gregorian calendar years that are divisible by 100 but not by 400 don't contain a leap day. Thus, 1700, 1800, and 1900 did not contain a leap day.

Comment: The reason behind the formula(s) is that (year length)/(day length) is either irrationall or a rational with a big denominator, so that you need ever finer adjustments to keep the Spring Equinox near 21 March. Of course the reason behind that is that Easter was getting too late (or was it early?)

Comment: It's a cludge.  The astronomical year is not exactly 365.25 days.  It's a little shorter.  So the gregorian calendar simply made up the rules Every year divisible by 4 is a leap year, except those divisible by 100 which are not, except those divisible by 400 which are.  This makes the average year ... lessee ... [365*400 regular days + 100 leap year - 3 century exceptions]/400=365.2425 which is pretty close to the reality.  We can fudge by adding and removing extra seconds every now and then.  There's no math reason; just cludging.

Comment: The mean tropical year is approximately 365.24219 days. This means our 365 day year is slightly off. So we adjust it be adding a leap day every four years (year is 365.25 days. But this is an slight over compensation so we don't have a leap year every hundred years (year is 365.24 days). But now the year is too short. So we add a leap year every 400 years (we had one in 1600 and 2000 and will in 2400).  Now the average year is 365.2425 which is too long but only by 26 seconds.   Which as the day isn't always 24 hours we adjust by adding "atomic" seconds every now and then. It's a giant cludge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The length of a [Tropical Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year) is approximately $365.2422$ mean solar days.

---

**Julian Calendar**

The [Julian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) approximates the length of a tropical year as
$$
365.25=365+\tfrac14
$$
Therefore, it adds one leap year every $4$ years.

Thus, every year that is divisible by $4$ is a leap year.

---

**Gregorian Calendar**

The [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) approximates the length of a tropical year as
$$
365.2425=365+\tfrac14-\tfrac1{100}+\tfrac1{400}
$$
Therefore, it adds one leap year every $4$ years, skipping one every $100$ years, but adding one back every $400$ years.

Thus, every year that is divisible by $4$ is a leap year except for those divisible by $100$ but not $400$.

Comment: Nice explanation...(+1)

Comment: Niiiice! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 5):

Leap years under the Julian calendar were those that are divisible by 4.

Leap years under the Gregorian calendar are those that are divisible by 4, except that those divisible by 100 are not, except that those divisible by 400 are.

Answer (score 1):

If you google "leap year" you will find that a year $n$ is a leap year if $n$ is divisible by $4$, *except* if $n$ is divisible by $100$. If it's divisible by $400$, though, it's still a leap year.

$1900$ is divisible by $100$, but not $400$, so it is not a leap year. $2000$, however, *was* a leap year.

Comment: I see - thanks@!

Answer (score 1):

By definition $n$ is a leap year if (i) $n$ is divisible by $400$ or (ii) $n$ is divisible by $4$ but *not* divisible by $100$.